# php hide iframe until certain date

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an iframe on my webpage, (it's a scoreboard for pro football) and currently it is blank, so it shows as a ugly black space on my site for now. When the football season starts, it will not be blank anymore. My question is, is there a way to hide the iframe until a certain date?

Comment: Can you not just edit it out of the page until the right date?

Comment: Yes, obviously, but it would be a lot nicer if it did it automatically.

Comment: use ajax part to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, thanks to ideas from Noble Mushtak and Harrald Torenvlied. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$date = time();

$SeasonStart = strtotime('2014-09-01 00:00:00');

if ($date > $SeasonStart) {
echo "<center><iframe src=\"http://example.com\" width=\"985\" height=\"50\" frameBorder=\"0\"></iframe></center>";
}
?>
```

The iframe will not show until after September 1st. (starting right at midnight)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to hide  the iframe with PHP.

What you want is to compare the date at which the football season starts `$startdate_footbal_season = new DateTime('2014-12-01');` with the date of this very moment `$now = new DateTime;`

Calculating the diff: `$diff = $now->diff($startdate_footbal_season);`

Now when `$diff->invert` equals `1`, that means we are past the `$startdate_footbal_season` date and thus we can show the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `getdate()` and using an `if` loop to output the `<iframe>` only if the current date is after the date you want it to be. For example, the below only writes the `<iframe>` element after June 30, 2014:

```
<?php
$currentTime = getdate();
if ($currentTime["year"] > 2013 && $currentTime["mon"] > 6) {
    echo "<iframe srcdoc=\"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n <title>Output frame</title>\n</head>\n<body>Hello!</body>\n</html>\"></iframe>";
}
?>
```

Comment: This works great, but I am a little confused on how you got the date... what does the "mon" mean? Say I wanted it to display after Sept. 4th, 2014... how would I do that? Thank you so much.

Comment: Look at the documentation for `getdate()` at http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.getdate.php